# workflow triggered in CRM by saving a docuemnt in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, crm

I am trying to find out if a workflow can be triggered in CRM to change the status of a field. the process is as follows and i am trying to autmate the process. I am talking about a process that will help us manage over 1000 documents in a year
1. save a document to SharePoint 
2. open CRM and update field

my question is can a workflow update a field in CRM when a document is saved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 and your CRM has a web service which can update that field, you can use the new functionality of SharePoint 2013 Workflow Platform Type which allows it to call web services.